# Why does adding a checkbox to an XML layout cause a java.lang.ClassCastException?

Tags: android, xml

I am modifying someone else's code, and just trying to add a fourth checkbox to the following dialog:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent"
  android:orientation="vertical">
<CheckBox 
    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="20dp" 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:text="@string/vinai_full" 
    android:checked="true"
    android:id="@+id/cb_vinai" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
<CheckBox 
    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="20dp" 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:text="@string/suttan_full" 
    android:checked="true"
    android:id="@+id/cb_suttan"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
<CheckBox 
    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="20dp" 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/abhidum_full" 
    android:checked="true"
    android:id="@+id/cb_abhidham" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
<Button 
    android:text="@string/ok"  
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:id="@+id/okcatebtn" 
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center" 
    />
</LinearLayout>
```

The fourth checkbox is:

```
<CheckBox 
    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="20dp" 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/etc_full" 
    android:checked="true"
    android:id="@+id/cb_etc" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

When I add it in, the apk compiles fine, but the program crashes on startup:

```
E/AndroidRuntime( 1470): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
E/AndroidRuntime( 1470): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{org.yuttadhammo.tipitaka/org.yuttadhammo.tipitaka.SelectBookActivity}: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.Gallery
E/AndroidRuntime( 1470):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1647)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1470):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1663)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1470):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1470):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:931)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1470):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1470):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1470):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1470):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1470):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1470):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1470):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1470):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1470): Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.Gallery
E/AndroidRuntime( 1470):    at org.yuttadhammo.tipitaka.SelectBookActivity.onCreate(SelectBookActivity.java:586)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1470):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1470):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1611)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1470):    ... 11 more
```

This is even though the dialog is not loaded at startup.  If I replace the third checkbox with the fourth one, there is no crash, so it seems like for some reason it is simply not accepting a fourth element.  Why would that be?

*EDIT: Here's the code leading up to the error, but I don't understand how it is related, since it refers to an element in a differing layout file:*

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    main =  View.inflate(this, R.layout.main, null);
    setContentView(main);

    searchHistoryDBAdapter = new SearchHistoryDBAdapter(SelectBookActivity.this);
    searchResultsDBAdapter = new SearchResultsDBAdapter(SelectBookActivity.this);
    bookmarkDBAdapter = new BookmarkDBAdapter(SelectBookActivity.this);

    Context context = getApplicationContext();
    prefs =  PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);

    MainTipitakaDBAdapter mainTipitakaDBAdapter = new MainTipitakaDBAdapter(this);
    try {
        mainTipitakaDBAdapter.open();
        if(mainTipitakaDBAdapter.isOpened()) {
            mainTipitakaDBAdapter.close();
        } else {
            startDownloader();
        }
    } catch (SQLiteException e) {
        Log.e ("Tipitaka","error:", e);
        startDownloader();
    }

    Resources res = getResources();
    final String [] cnames = res.getStringArray(R.array.category);

    textInfo = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text_info);
```

and here's main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<ScrollView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/ScrollView01" 
    android:layout_width="match_parent" 
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:scrollbars="horizontal|vertical">
    <LinearLayout    
        android:id="@+id/LinearLayout01"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:padding="3dp"
            android:id="@+id/about_header">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/about_text_1"
                android:layout_marginLeft="1dp"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@id/about_logo"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:text="Android Tipitaka"
                android:textSize="24sp"
                android:textColor="@android:color/primary_text_dark_nodisable"/>    

        </RelativeLayout>       

        <View 
            android:background="@drawable/black_white_gradient"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            android:layout_height="2dp"/>
        <Gallery 
            android:layout_width="match_parent" 
            android:id="@+id/gallery_cate" 
            android:spacing="6dp" 
            android:gravity="center_vertical" 
            android:layout_height="60dp"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/book_label"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:text="@string/th_book_label"
            android:textSize="17sp"
        />

        <Gallery 
            android:id="@+id/gallery_ncate" 
            android:layout_width="match_parent" 
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:spacing="25dp"

        />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text_info"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:lines="2"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal|center"
            android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
            android:text=""
            android:textSize="17sp"
        />

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/main_buttons"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal">
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/read_btn"
                android:layout_width="85dp" 
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal|center"
                android:text="@string/th_read"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:textSize="16dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="40dp"
            />
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/search_btn"
                android:text="@string/th_search"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@id/read_btn"
                android:layout_width="85dp" 
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal|center"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:textSize="16dp"
            />
        </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: what does SelectBookActivity.java:586 contain

Comment: edit post with code SelectBookActivity.class

Comment: Thanks, I've added it, but I don't see how it is related... then again, I'm still learning Java...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if text_info is in diffrent layout then use this

```
textInfo = (TextView)your_layout.findViewById(R.id.text_info);
```

instead of

```
textInfo = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.text_info);
```

Comment: thanks, but I'm pretty sure this is not the problem... text_info is in the main layout, but the checkboxes are in a dialog that isn't called on startup, afaics.  Again, it's just a matter of adding a fourth checkbox to the uncalled dialog.

Comment: @Yuttadhammo : i checked your code step by step as u shared in this code you have not issure can u post other part of code and full xml then we will find exact problem

Comment: thanks; what part of the code should I add? it's a pretty big project.  The entire project is on github: https://github.com/ssutee/E-Tipitaka-for-Android, but I've made some modifications, so they might be the problem as well.

Comment: This seems to have fixed the problem, just using `this.findViewById()`

Answer (score 0):

Be sure when you use

```
myContext.findViewById(R.id.cb_etc);
```

You assign it to a CheckBox object.

```
CheckBox mCheckBox = (CheckBox) myContext.findViewById(R.id.cb_etc);
```

NOTE: If you are using another layout, then you need to cast findViewBy id with that layout or the Context of the layout.

Comment: Thanks, I'm doing that:      boolean b4 = ((CheckBox) cateDialog.findViewById(R.id.cb_etc)).isChecked();  but this code is not run at start up, it's only a search dialog that is fired on a button click.

Answer (score 0):

I had also same problem. but i add an attribute in Linearlayout for id

```
       <LinearLayout
               xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
               android:id="@+id/mainlayout"
               android:layout_width="fill_parent"
               android:layout_height="fill_parent"
               android:orientation="vertical">
```

and it solved.

Comment: thanks, this actually helped... but now it's throwing the error for the next line: readBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.read_btn); since read_btn is in the main.xml layout as well, I am really confused as to what is the problem.

Comment: can u post code of main.xml here? coz v need to see code for read_btn.

Comment: does your R.java file contains                                        public static final class id {
        public static final int read_btn=0x7f050000;
    }     ?

Answer (score 0):

Actually, the answer turned out to be running `ant clean` - the problem was there were cached files in the gen directory that were causing confusion for the device.